# Label font size and scale QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, labeling, zoom, font

How can I make it that the font size of the label changes when I zoom in and out? I have a polygon and I want the label get bigger when I zoom in and smaller when I zoom out (just like the polygon does). I tried to use map points but it didn't work.

Comment: I use the following conversion: If the map scale is 1:20 000, 1pt = 7.056 map units and 1mm = 20 mu if the map scale is 1:50 000, 1pt = 17.64 mu and 1mm = 50 mu At my workplace, these days, we really only use those two map scales. Some of our ArcMap symbology is measured in pt and some in mm which is why I need to convert both.

Answer (score 8):

Right-click on your layer -> Properties... -> Labels ->

According to your CRS, you can use "Meters at scale" or "Map Units"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the size unit to Map Units. You might have to make this a very high number depending on the scale of your map, for instance in the project I'm working on at the moment at 1:260000 I have to set fonts to 700 map units to match the original 8pt text.